# How to solve this ASP.NET MVC data null constructor warning on DbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

[Screenshot of My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeMFe.png)

The following code is from the official MS documentation; I followed as same for to solve this warning issues.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MvcMovie.Models;

namespace MvcMovie.Data
{
    public class MvcMovieContext : DbContext
    {
        public MvcMovieContext (DbContextOptions<MvcMovieContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<MvcMovie.Models.Movie> Movie { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[official MS Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Everything in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#dbcontext-and-dbset)

Comment: Make it Nullable using `?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the document link you posted , you should have founnd this warning

"To eliminate the warnings from nullable reference types, REMOVE the following line from the MvcMovie.csproj file "

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Answer (score 2):

In you MvcMovieContext class, instread that :

```
public DbSet<MvcMovie.Models.Movie> Movie { get; set; }
```

Simply do that :

```
public DbSet<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>? Movie { get; set; }
```

And it's done. Otherwise tell me if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank You its Working fine now without any warring

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to click on the upper arrow on the answer for validate it.

Comment: But this will cause a null warning everywhere else that I use 'Movie'.

Answer (score 0):

The best way remove this line in .csproj => Nullable enable Nullable
If you do like this :

```
public DbSet<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>? Movie { get; set; }
```

It will Warning in other files